# "Undefined index" e "Cannot access empty property"

Tags: php

Olá, pessoal! Embora haja muitas postagens aqui no Stack com relação a este problema, nenhuma delas foi suficiente para que eu pudesse resolver o meu.

Estou criando um painel admin de um site cuja página inicial é basicamente um calendário, em cujas datas que contêm eventos é possível clicar e abrir páginas com conteúdos de aula.

No admin.php, criei um formulário para cadastrar novas datas ao mesmo tempo em que é criada automaticamente uma página com alguns recursos para que o professor ponha nela conteúdo. O formulário possui 3 campos: Título, Data e Encontro.

Então, eu estava editando o arquivo cadastrando.php e resolvi fazer com que no último campo do formulário (chamado "encontro") fosse incluído no banco de dados, automaticamente, o mesmo nome escrito pelo professor no campo título, acrescido de ".php" (que se tornaria o nome do arquivo da nova página criada). Depois eu apagaria o campo "encontro", para ninguém escrever nada dentro. Mas nem cheguei a fazer isso, já que o erro descrito no título desta postagem ocorreu e toda a página do admin ficou desconfigurada, desaparecendo inclusive o calendário.

Ocorre que, embora eu estivesse mexendo no arquivo cadastrando.php, o erro descreve um problema em calendario.php, que estava funcionando normalmente até então e não foi mexido.

Enfim, se alguém puder dar uma luz, agradeço muitíssimo.

Eis o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*calendário.php linha 12:

```
 $encontro = $info['encontro'];
```

*calendário.php linha 20:

```
 'encontro' => $row->{$encontro}
```

Eis os códigos:

no admin.php (na parte que interessa):

```
<!--cadastrar evento--> 
    <div class="item-main-admin">

        <p2><center>
        <form name="cadastrarevento" method="post" action="cadastrando.php">
        Título: <input type="text" name="titulo" value="encontro-"/> </br>
        Data: <input type="text" name="data" placeholder="aaaa/mm/dd" /> </br>
        Encontro: <input type="text" name="encontro" /> </br>
        <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar evento" />
        </form>
        </p2></center>
    </div>




<!--calendario-->
<div class="item-main-admin">
    <?php 
    $eventos = montaEventos($info);
    montaCalendario($eventos); 
    ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/administrador/calendario/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/administrador/calendario/functions.js"></script>
```

---

No cadastrando.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE & ~ E_DEPRECATED);
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$banco = "calendario";
$conexao = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($banco) or die(mysql_error());
?>


<?php
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
?>


<?php

$titulo=$_POST['titulo'];
$data=$_POST['data'];
$encontro=$_POST['encontro'];


$myFile = "$titulo.php";


$result = mysql_query("SELECT titulo FROM eventos WHERE titulo = '$titulo'");

if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
        echo "O título $titulo já existe. Crie um diferente.";
        } else {

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO eventos(titulo, data, encontro) 
    VALUES('$titulo', '$data', '$encontro')");


$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');

$stringData = "<html><?php include 'template.php';?></html>";   


fwrite($fh, $stringData);
//header('Location: ' . $myFile);
fclose($fh);


?>



<div class="cadastro_ok">
<div id="item-cadastro_ok">
    <img src="imagens/ok.png" />
</div>
<div id="item-cadastro_ok">
    <?php echo "Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!"; ?>
</div>
</div>

<?php } ?>



<?php
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=admin.php" />';
?>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

---

****OBS.: eu havia colocado assim ($myFile no lugar de $encontro), e em seguida tive o erro, embora não pareça vir daí:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO eventos(titulo, data, encontro) 
    VALUES('$titulo', '$data', '$myFile')");
```

E no calendario.php:

```
<?php

function num($num){
    return ($num < 10) ? '0'.$num : $num;
}
function montaEventos($info){
    global $pdo;
    //tabela, data, titulo, encontro
    $tabela = $info['tabela'];
    $data = $info['data'];
    $titulo = $info['titulo'];
    $encontro = $info['encontro'];
    $eventos = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `".$tabela."` ");
    $eventos->execute();
    $retorno = array();
    while($row = $eventos->fetchObject()){
        $dataArr = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->{$data}));
        $retorno[$dataArr] = array(
            'titulo' => $row->{$titulo},
            'encontro' => $row->{$encontro}
        );
    }
    return $retorno;
}
function diasMeses(){
    $retorno = array();
    for($i = 1; $i<=12;$i++){
        $retorno[$i] = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $i, date('Y'));
    }
    return $retorno;
}
function montaCalendario($eventos = array()){
    $daysWeek = array(
        'Sun',
        'Mon',
        'Tue',
        'Wed',
        'Thu',
        'Fri',
        'Sat'
    );
    $diasSemana = array(
        'Dom',
        'Seg',
        'Ter',
        'Qua',
        'Qui',
        'Sex',
        'Sab'
    );
    $arrayMes = array(
        1 => 'Janeiro',
        2 => 'Fevereiro',
        3 => 'Março',
        4 => 'Abril',
        5 => 'Maio',
        6 => 'Junho',
        7 => 'Julho',
        8 => 'Agosto',
        9 => 'Setembro',
        10 => 'Outubro',
        11 => 'Novembro',
        12 => 'Dezembro'
    );
    $diasMeses = diasMeses();
    $arrayRetorno = array();
    for($i =1; $i <= 12; $i++){
        $arrayRetorno[$i] = array();
        for($n=1; $n<= $diasMeses[$i]; $n++){
            $dayMonth = gregoriantojd($i, $n, date('Y'));
            $weekMonth = substr(jddayofweek($dayMonth, 1),0,3);
            if($weekMonth == 'Mun') $weekMonth = 'Mon';
            $arrayRetorno[$i][$n] = $weekMonth;
        }
    }
    echo '<a href="#" id="volta">&laquo;</a><a href="#" id="vai">&raquo;</a>';
    echo '<table border="0" width="100%">';
    foreach($arrayMes as $num => $mes){
        echo '<tbody id="mes_'.$num.'" class="mes">';
        echo '<tr class="mes_title"><td colspan="7">'.$mes.'</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr class="dias_title">';
        foreach($diasSemana as $i => $day){
            echo '<td>'.$day.'</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr><tr>';
        $y = 0;
        foreach($arrayRetorno[$num] as $numero => $dia){
            $y++;
            if($numero == 1){
                $qtd = array_search($dia, $daysWeek);
                for($i=1; $i<=$qtd; $i++){
                    echo '<td></td>';
                    $y+=1;
                }
            }
            if(count($eventos) > 0){
                $month = num($num);
                $dayNow = num($numero);
                $date = date('Y').'-'.$month.'-'.$dayNow;
                if(in_array($date, array_keys($eventos))){
                    $evento = $eventos[$date];
                    echo '<td class="evento"><a href="'.$evento['encontro'].'" title="'.$evento['titulo'].'">'.$numero.'</a></td>';
                }else{
                    echo '<td class="dia_'.$numero.'">'.$numero.'</td>';
                }
            }else{
                echo '<td class="dia_'.$numero.'">'.$numero.'</td>';
            }
            if($y == 7){
                $y=0;
                echo '</tr><tr>';
            }
        }
        echo '</tr></tbody>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Quais dados a variável `$info` possui na função `montaEventos`? Qual erro aparece na tela? Por que utilizar `$row->{$titulo}` e não `$row->nome_da_coluna_do_db`?

Comment: Oi Valdeir! Editei a pergunta para inserir nela o print do erro, que direciona melhor a investigação do problema. Perdão pela mancada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro é porque o index `encontra` em `$info['encontro']`. A variável `$info` no método `montaEventos` não traz um valor.

Para corrigir isso, você deverá utilizar um [operador ternário](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Ele funciona da seguinte forma:

`(expr1) ? value1 : value2;`

Ele vai comparar a `expr1`, caso ela seja verdadeira, retorna `value1`, caso contrário, retorna `value2`

Esse *ternário* nada mais é que um `if..else` é uma linha só.

---

Para corrigir esse erro você deve criar uma condição para verificar se o conteúdo `$info['encontro']` existe, caso não exista, você pode adicionar um novo valor ou retornar `null`.

Ex (*PHP 7+*): `$encontro = $info['encontro'] ?? null;`

Ex (*PHP 5+*): `$encontro = isset($info['encontro']) ? $info['encontro'] : "valor qualquer";`

Dessa forma, quando o índice `encontro` **não** existir na variável `$info`, a variável `$encontro` terá o valor de null.

---

O segundo erro é porque a `query` abaixo, não traz a coluna com o nome que está sendo definido na variável `$encontro` (devido essa variável não receber um valor).

```
"SELECT * FROM `".$tabela."`"
```

Para corrigir esse erro, é necessário substituir `'encontro' => $row->{$encontro}` por:

```
'encontro' => ($encontro == null) ? "Valor qualquer" : $row->{$encontro}
```

> Você também pode adicionar um `var_export($row);` antes de `$dataArr = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->{$data}));` para verificar o que a `query` traz no resultado.

Comment: Entendi então o problema! Obrigado, Valdeir!